# if statements in adobe edge/javascript

Tags: javascript, adobe-edge

I have an animation in Edge that, when clicked, will play from a different position each time, depending on the current location of the playhead.

```
Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${b}", "click", function(sym, e) 
 {
    var pos = sym.getPosition();


   if (pos <= 16000) {
   sym.play("catch1");
    }

   if (pos > 22500 && pos < 3800) {
   sym.play("catch2");
}
```

It has no trouble entering the first if statement, but never enters the second, even if `pos` is the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

Well it is sort of impossible for a number to be both greater than 22500 and less than 3800 at the same time.